# Reclaim search console property ownership after the owner who invited me has been removed

Tags: google-search-console

I have access to search console but the owner who invited me left the company. Do you know how to claim ownership for our existing property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to verify ownership of your website.   You can do so through any of methods that Google supports:

- HTML file upload
- Domain name provider
- HTML tag
- Google Analytics tracking code
- Google Tag Manager container snippet
- Google Sites
- Blogger

[Google has a help document](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35179?hl=en) with detailed instructions.  It includes instructions on how to change your verification method and instructions for each of the individual methods that you might choose.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the site in search console yourself and then adding the .txt file verification at the root of the domain?

You could also delete the current .txt file on the server and this should eventually cause search console to remove the previous ownership. You'll most likely lose the data you have in this process, but you'll get to reclaim ownership once the current ownership drops from the verification.txt removal.